# Python Sphinx Validate and update schema

Tags: python-sphinx, docutils

I'm using Sphinx to maintain docs on a project, I am generating a jsonschema document from a tool where all properties of objects are listed.
Those objects properties are documented in rst files, I need to:
I've managed to read the rst files in the `doctree-resolved` event, and match with the json property, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach since I need

a) check all properties are documented, this is almost donde, I can mark on the json properties found and then check the json at the end.

b) Copy the description retrieved from the doctree object in the json (adding a property to the json) the format I need is markup, so I need to figure out how to convert a doctree node(set) to markup. Also the url links should be working at this stage. Also if markdown is not possible converting the fragment to html then to markdown might be easier

I don't know if I'm in the right path or should I write a builder instead?

Thanks

Comment: This is a lot of functionality without any example code. If you could add a working example it would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks bad_coder, actually I don't have problem with a piece of code yet, I'm still researching my approach, so far found rst2md on GH which might solve part of b, if I got it working I'll update the question.